# using powershell to apply formulas to Exel Groups based on other colums

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am very new to PowerShell and am trying to automate an invoicing process I do. 
I have been able to group my excel data into "records" where each repair # in column A has multiple rows of parts and diagnostics.

where I am stuck is having PowerShell loop through each record reading the information in Columns J-M and providing a corresponding payment in Column H.

[this is a picture of the excel file that the invoice is processed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOtDO.png)

This is the code that groups my rows to their corresponding repair #

```
$intRowCount = $ws2.usedRange.Rows.Count     
for($i=6; $i -le $intRowCount; $i++)

{
    if($ws2.Cells.Item($i,1).text -like "")
    {
        $startRow = $i 
        for($j=$i+1; $j -le $intRowCount; $j++)
        {
            if($ws2.cells.Item($j,1).text -ne "" -or $j -eq $intRowCount)
            {
                $endRow = $j-1
                if($j -eq $intRowCount)
                {
                    $endRow = $j
                }
                break
            }
        }
        $str = "A"+$startRow+":A"+$endRow
        $ws2.Range($str).Rows.Group()
        $i=$j
    }
}
```

Any help would be great, as I have been doing this manually for months going through thousands of lines of data.

Comment: From a programmers point of view it's much easier to populate all cells in column A and possibly use a conditional formatting to shade/colour the cell if the value is the same as it's predecessor.

Comment: i've thought about that, but this sheet already has a fair amount of conditional formatting in it and I don't want it to get too complex.